# Spring Boot - spring-boot-starter-mail Sending Email for Smartermail not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail, restful-url

I have an existing Java Spring Boot project that been using Gmail for sending out email such as forgot password for our web system.

Recently we are moving to production as we are using Smartermail as our company email. The same Java Mail Code wrapper from Spring Boot that is working with Gmail SMTP is now not working after changing the configuration to smartermail SMTP.

However, I have tried to connect it from **my Android phone email app** using the same Smartermail configuration and credential, and it is **all working**.

Here is my application.properties content snapshot:

```
# Email setting
com.eurogain.portal.emailFrom=postmaster@myowndomain.com
spring.mail.host=mail.myowndomain.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=user1@myowndomain.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=15000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=15000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=15000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

There are no error, and the above code the reason I put the timeout shorter is because without it,  it will keep on running without any stop.

Any advise or tips? Appreciate the helps.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can make an outgoing SMTP connection at all from the zone where your server application is deployed? SMTP is often heavily firewalled at several points because of spam. You also should be getting some kind of error messages in the server output, even if only "Connection timeout".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was confirmed by the system admin that the port 465 here is for secure encryption type. The non-secure port is 587.

Still, in that case, does that mean Java Sprint Boot email doesn't support the secure type?